# How to derive and solve a spherical mass integral

Tags: integration, summation

Using the formula $\sqrt{AB/4G}$ multiplied by a radius, I can determine the mass of the solid red sphere at the center of the attached image.

However, at distances greater than that radius, the constant $B$ in the formula decreases as a function of increasing radius thereby decreasing the mass or mass density as a function of radius.

As such, using this formula as a base, how do I create an integral to determine the total amount of mass that exists between points 1 & 2, which will always be greater than the radius of the solid red sphere?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: We may need some more contexts to understand your question, for example, what's $A,B$? What's the annulus around the solid red sphere? And what exactly do you mean by 'the mass between 1 & 2'?

Comment: I'll try to provide some context. Using the formula $\sqrt(AB/4G)$ produces the maximum density of a substance and when multiplied by a radius gives the total mass of that substance. However, as that radius increases the constant $B$ reduces as the radius gets larger, decreasing density of the substance, Therefore, as density decreases as radius increases, how can I determine the total mass of the substance that exists between any two radii > solid red radius? I'm not trying to solve the equation just create the integral that could.  Like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMXshJn5kEE